# Install In-House iOS App wirelessly with manifest.plist does not work anymore with iOS 8

Tags: ios

We have In-House distribution scheme, which includes both .ipa and manifest.plist files placed on a web-server. A simple web-page allows user to choose the app version and tap to install it. When user taps on the link in Safari on iPad with iOS 8, it asks would he like to install the app and after pressing "Install" do nothing. No errors or installation progress icon...

This scheme we used for year before and I could confirm it works with iOS 7 as well with iOS 8 beta (at the moment also). It doesn't work with iOS 8. It seems like iOS 8 blocks it. Does anybody already faced the issue or knows how to around it?

The server has MIME types set:

**- application/octet-stream ipa

 - text/xml plist**

The manifest.plist file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://example.com:8079/foo.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.example.fooapp</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Example Corporate App</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also just change the bundle id in your `Manifest.plist` file like:

```
<key>bundle-identifier</key>
<string>com.example.fooappNew</string>
```

Without regenerating the provisioning profiles.

Comment: You saved my life, man! Your solution is simple and quite easy. After app installed the system asks trust or not unsigned developer, - tap trust and launch the app!

Comment: Jeez, it did the trick. It showed a *second* app icon while downloading and installing but once installed the original icon was replaced and could be launched. I'm wondering if this could cause some other issues you are aware of? If not would it maybe make sense to include an update of the bundle identifier in my deployment produce so it will always be e.g. "bundle-identifier-version-xyz"?

Comment: Peter, it seems like the app installed previously should be deleted before the trick.

Comment: Please note apple fixed this issue in iOS 9 and apps will not install properly if the bundle identifier in the plist does not match the bundle identifier embedded in the app.

Comment: Hi I am struggling to add Inhouse app please help me to do?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with my App.  Fixed by changing App bundle name, creating new App Id, and building new provisioning profile.

Comment: Hi, David! I've tried to do the same and it worked! Thank you so much! It looks like your solution is only one to around the issue.

Comment: Hi i need help to create  manifest.plist . how do i kick start?