# Install ipa on iOS via Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, safari, ipa

I need to install an **ipa** file via Safari. I'm using this thred to lean how to do [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios) but I'm not able to install it.
I'm running iOS 11 beta 3 and probably I'm not able to obtain license to install app. In which way can I do it?
I'm using this [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934131/install-in-house-ios-app-wirelessly-with-manifest-plist-does-not-work-anymore-wi) to compile *manifest.plist* and I toke data from *iTunesMetadata.plist* stored into ipa file.
I have all the permissions to install ipa (from developer) but I'm not able to install it.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative way to install via Safari:**

I understood that by doing all these steps you want to install your .ipa file on your iPhone through the link. The same benefit is offering by different services like [Diawi](https://diawi.com/). Installing using this links are very easy.

Comment: Thx! Yes, it's really good but I would to learn how to do manually.