# How to create .IPA file and install app without development account for Xcode 7.2 and iOS 12

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm sorry in advance if this question has been asked a couple of times before, but I have been reading and trying different solutions for hours now with no luck.

I have an iPhone running iOS 12 for development, and an Apple ID with free developer account, and a mac running on version 10.10, and it doesn't belong to me so I cannot upgrade the system. Unfortunately, it means I'm stuck at Xcode 7.2, which doesn't support iOS 12, I have tried installing the image disks already, but that didn't help as I still can't normally build and run the app to my iPhone by just connecting the iPhone.

I was wondering if there's any other way I can get the app on my iPhone without paying for a full development account? This seems nearly impossible to me at this point but I hope you can help me out.
I would normally opt for just simulating the app, but this one relies completely on the gyroscope of the device so I need to test it on an actual device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once your iPhone has iOS12 it's a game over for Xcode 7.2. However you can self-sign code and distribute it using web with manifest file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934131/install-in-house-ios-app-wirelessly-with-manifest-plist-does-not-work-anymore-wi

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm well aware that it's pretty much game over for the regular development process. My problem is that I cannot generate an IPA to use for installation without a developer account

Comment: "I have an... and an Apple ID with free developer account". It is sufficient to sign it with development certificate. This is how I install pokemon with cydia impactor. Free dev account. However the binary will expire within a week (can't last long). Remember to give trust to the dev certificate in Settings->General once IPA is on iPhone. So one solution for you is to use Cydia Impactor (doesn't require jailbreak)